# New table Mobile Service Azure, can't get data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

How can I add additional tables in azure mobile services and programmatically insert and read data. I tried doing it similarly as the code from TodoItems table. My new table is created and I can insert data manually by using sql, but when I use

```
private MobileServiceCollection<User,User> users;
private IMobileServiceTable<User> userTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<User>();
```

and

```
users = await userTable.ToCollectionAsync();
```

I get

```
if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Do you have any ideas how I can do it?

Comment: Is this using the Mobile Services Node.JS backend or the .NET backend? Was the table created by the service, or manually in SQL?

Comment: It is .NET backend, i created table by the service, in VS i created new class in DataObjects and in myprojectContext.cs include this: public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt points out, to add a table to a .NET backend, you just add a new property to the Code First data model that returns a DbSet based on a new model data type (which inherits from the [EntityData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.mobile.service.entitydata.aspx) type).

Make sure that you also read the topic [How to make data model changes to a .NET backend mobile service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/) to learn about what happens when you try to change the data model of a .NET backend mobile service.

Comment: link is not valid anymore

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the .NET backend you'll need to do the following:

1. Create a new entity that represents the item in your table. Be sure
   you use the right base class.
2. Add a new TableController to the controllers folder and select your new entity class and your EF context class in the wizard.

This should provide the API you need and automatically add the DBset property to the ef context for you. Don't forget to publish your application to Azure if you are testing against the deployed version and not the local version.

If you can provide more details on the exception you get when you hit that breakpoint, it would help. Check the locals window in Visual Studio or examine the arguments to the current method.

Comment: what wizard is that?

Comment: The wizard or dialog that comes up when you right-click the project and add->controller and select the Table Controller template. It asks for those details before actually creating the controller code.